# How can I find the charset given a char and its hex representation?

Tags: hex, non-ascii-characters

I will use an example, but the question goes for any similar case. If I have:

- A character (for instance, `€`)
- Its hexadecimal representation (for this one, `C3A2C2809AC2AC`). I just know it stands for `€`.

How can I, using this information, find out which charset matches this relationship?